When using openai assistants v2, which models are supported?
I have some old code running with openai assistants beta v1 using model gpt-4-1106-preview and I'm trying to follow steps in:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/migration
To upgrade to v2. It all works if I keep the model the same but when I try and use any gpt-4o model I get unsupported_model error. Is this just something you can't use with assistants?

The OpenAI Assistants API v2 supports the following models, as of today:

GPT-4o (except chatgpt-4o-latest),
GPT-4o-mini,
GPT-4, and
GPT-3.5 Turbo.

The retrieval tool requires:

gpt-4-turbo-preview (and subsequent dated model releases), or
gpt-3.5-turbo-1106 (and subsequent dated model releases).

See the official OpenAI documentation on model endpoint compatibility.
